# filter Access 2010 database using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2010

I have created the following code and want to filter my database table by landlord_ID. No errors have been shown and when I debug it all seems to go well (all the landlord_IDs come up with all the information e.g how many properties).

However, when I double-click to select a certain ID nothing happens. If I add to part of the code like this :

```
SQLString = "SELECT = FROM Flats WHERE landlord_ID = 1" '& landlord_ID & ""
```

Then number 1 comes up but so do all the others (the rest should be filtered out).
Also, I have used this YouTube link to help me: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4H2g8H0bqEg

Finally, This is my first time using Visual Studio (2010 Ultimate and the Access database was made on Access 2010) so I do not know much so would appreciate answers that are a little more specific.

Thank you for reading all of this and I hope you can help me

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1

   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       OleDbDataAdapter2.Fill(DataSet11)
   End Sub

   Private Sub lstLID_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstLID.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim landlord_ID, SQLString As String
        Dim dtFlats As New DataTable()
        Dim dbDataAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim ConnectString As String = "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source = Database.accdb"
        landlord_ID = lstLID.Text
        SQLString = "SELECT = FROM Flats WHERE landlord_ID = " '& landlord_ID & ""
        dbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLString, ConnectString)
        dbDataAdapter.Fill(dtFlats)
        grdFlats.DataSource = dtFlats
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems with

```
SQLString = "SELECT = FROM Flats WHERE landlord_ID = " '& landlord_ID & ""
```

1. `SELECT = FROM` should probably be `SELECT * FROM`
2. `WHERE landlord_ID = " '& landlord_ID & ""` if the apostrophe `'` is a comment character in VB.NET then everything after it will be ignored.